# Setting a PHP object property where the parent property may not initially exist

Tags: php, arrays, object

Given object `$obj`, how do I set `$obj->foo[4]->bar[2]->fee->fi->fo->fum` equal to "hello", and create the parent arrays and objects if they don't currently exist?

Given object `$obj`, and string `foo[4]->bar[2]->fee->fi->fo->fum`, is there any way to similarly do so?

Comment: What? You want to dynamically create said object? All you need: `$obj = new stdClass(); $obj->foo[4]->bar[2]->fee->fi->fo->fum = 'hello'; var_dump($obj->foo[4]->bar[2]->fee->fi->fo->fum);` ? [Example](http://www.tehplayground.com/#a8ndC1gz7)

Comment: @Darren  I have an existing object, and wish to add or modify a given property.

Comment: @Darren  I thought that I would get some sort of "property or index not set error".  I will test doing so, but didn't expect it to be that easy.

Comment: Too be honest, I didn't expect it to be that easy either haha!

Comment: Wow, it works!!!  Thank you!

Comment: Want to leave an answer?  If not, maybe I will delete this question to mask my ignorance.  I would rather, however, select your answer.

Comment: It is not that easy, probably you have Warnings disabled or display_errors off. I got with PHP 5.6:PHP Warning:  Creating default object from empty value in ... If it generates a warning is because is not completely correct ;)

Comment: Ah, I knew it wasn't as easy as expected :(  I only tested it on tehplayground, and they must have warnings silent.  I feel all warnings are not good to leave in script.

Comment: @Darren  Sorry Darren, maybe you don't want to give that answer.

Comment: Turns out I had errors off too lol - **but**, this does work as the objects have inbuilt [Dynamic Binding](http://krisjordan.com/dynamic-properties-in-php-with-stdclass). Looking how to do it via `__get()`/`__set()` methods/implementations haha

Comment: I know the title doesn't say "array", but the example has arrays as well.  Guess some `is_array()` if/then might work, and do as appropriate?

Comment: An ugly, and not very serious suggestion: if you didn't have to deal with the indexes, you could be a very hackish and doing the following: `$a['foo']['bar']['baz'] = 'hello'; $o = json_decode(json_encode($a));`. This converts the whole structure into a nested `stdClass` structure - no arrays. The problem with indexes with this approach is that they become sort of scalar properties and have to be dereferenced in a very ugly manner; e.g: `$o->foo->{'1'}`.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is a proposal, it works, not sure if it is the more elegant but works:

```
$obj = new stdClass();
$stringParams = "foo[4]->bar[2]->fee->fi->fo->fum";
$attributes = explode("->", $stringParams);
foreach($attributes as $attribute) {

    $attributeBase = explode("[", $attribute);

    if(count($attributeBase) > 1) {
        $attributeIndex = (int)str_ireplace("]","", $attributeBase[1]);
        $obj->$attributeBase[0] = [$attributeIndex => null];
    } else {
        $obj->{$attribute} = null;
    }

}

var_dump($obj);
```

Comment: Thanks Eduardo,  Not that un-elegant.  I was actually coming up with something similar but less elegant.  I don't think it quite does work however.  http://www.tehplayground.com/#1vtzImU1W

Comment: Yes, noticed an issue with arrays, I am reviewing it now

Comment: Fixed, please check

Comment: It seems tehplayground does not support new [] for array just change it for array()

Comment: I missed something pretty important they are nested

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much stole Darren's idea, but added one `@` character.  Still don't like the idea of suppressing errors or warnings of any kind.  Doesn't address the additional question how to access if the path is given as a string, but that wasn't the primary question.

```
<?php
$obj = new stdClass();
@$obj->foo[4]->bar[2]->fee->fi->fo->fum = 'hello';
echo($obj->foo[4]->bar[2]->fee->fi->fo->fum);
```